# Virtual functions, function overloading, inheritance

Tags: c++, virtual

why its not printing 'doub'? Looking for a detailed explanation. Thanks for your time!

```
#include<iostream.h>
using namespace std;

class B{
 public:
 virtual  int ft(int i) { cout <<"int"; return 0;}
};
class D: public B {
 public:
  double ft(double i){cout << "doub"; return 0.0;}
  int ft(int i) { cout <<"intdoub"; return 0;}
};

int main(){
 B *pB = new D;
 pB->ft(2.3);
}
```

o/p is 'intdoub'

Comment: What does it print? Anything? Is `cout` working in your app?

Comment: And what is it printing?

Comment: What *is* it printing? Also, why are you using the really old `iostream.h` and not `iostream`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The variable `pB` is of type `B*` and does not know about the function `double D::ft(double)`, only `virtual int B::ft(int)`. The conversion of the `double` value `2.3` to `int` happens automatically, although you should have gotten a compiler warning.

Try:

```
dynamic_cast<D*>(pB)->ft(2.3);
dynamic_cast<D*>(pB)->B::ft(2.3);
```

Comment: @user946850 "pB is of type B* and does not know about the function" is it because of object slicing?

Comment: The answer is correct. I wanted to add that the program will output `intdoub` though.

Comment: @sree: No, object slicing seems to be a different problem. Generally you see only the members defined in the base class when accessing a pointer to the base class.

Comment: "should have gotten a compiler warning": this is not required by the standard, and in most contexts it would be annoying.

Comment: @user946850 - not just generally; when you have a pointer to a type `T`, you can access members of `T`. It doesn't matter if there's a type derived from `T` somewhere, nor does it matter if the type of the object that the pointer points to is actually a type derived from `T`.

Comment: "dynamic_cast<D*>(pB)->ft(2.3)" is working as expected I got the o/p 'doub'. Thank you user946850 for the input!

Comment: @PeteBecker: An implicit conversion of `double` to `int` doesn't deserve a warning? At least on CodePad, it does: http://codepad.org/HjPbb0Zx

Comment: @user946850 - when I write it, it doesn't "deserve" anything. The conversion is well-defined and useful.

Comment: @PeteBecker: ...and error-prone, and I haven't seen a single C++ compiler or Lint tool that wouldn't be upset about it regardless what the standard says about which I'm not going to argue with you given your expertise :-)

Comment: @user946850 - there are many things more error-prone than converting floating-point values to integral values. Yes, it's possible to get a compiler to warn you about this, and if that's what you want, by all means do it. Don't express your preference as a moral judgment; such code doesn't "deserve" a warning, nor is it appropriate to say that a compiler "should" give a warning.